# How to create multiple threads dynamically in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, dynamic

I am creating a python code that have a function which should be run for number of times user asks using threads. Eg:

```
import time
T = input("Enter the number of times the function should be executed")
L = [1,2,3,4]

def sum(Num):
    for n in Num:
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print("square:",n*n)
```

Based on the value of T from user, I want tho create T’ number of threads dynamically and execute the sum function in separate threads.

If user gives input as 4 then I need to create 4 threads dynamically and execute the same function with 4 different threads.
Please help me out to create 4 multiple threads.Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It depends on your needs, you have several ways to do. Here is two examples suitable for your case

### With threading module

If you want to create `N` threads and wait for them to end. You should use the `threading` module and import `Thread`.

```
from threading import Thread

# Start all threads. 
threads = []
for n in range(T):
    t = Thread(target=sum, args=(L,))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

# Wait all threads to finish.
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

### With thread module

Otherwise, in case you do not want to wait. I strongly advise you to use the `thread` module *(renamed `_thread` since Python3)*.

```
from _thread import start_new_thread

# Start all threads and ignore exit.
for n in range(T):
    start_new_thread(sum, (L,))
```

`(args,)` are a tuple. It's why `L` is in parantheses.

Comment: `(n)` is not a tuple, it's just an int with redundant parentheses. `(n,)` would be a tuple. Anyway, it seems it should rather be `(L,)` because `sum` tries to iterate over the parameter passed to it. Also `for n in T` does not work, ints are not iterable. You probably meant `for n in range(T)`.

Comment: @SUПΣYΛ  , the first part of your answer need to be edited also to correct "for n in T:" to "for n in range(T):" and "args=(n)" to "args=(L,)"

Answer (score 0):

S U П Σ Y Λ answer explains well how to use multi-threading, but didn't take into account user input, which, according to your question, defines the number of threads. Based on that, you can try:

```
import threading, time

def _sum(n):
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print(f"square: {n*n}")

while 1:

    t = input("Enter the number of times the function should be executed:\n").strip()
    try:
        max_threads = int(t)
        for n in range(0, max_threads):
            threading.Thread(target=_sum, args=[n]).start()
    except:
        pass
        print("Please type only digits (0-9)")
        continue

    print(f"Started {max_threads} threads.")

    # wait threads to finish
    while threading.active_count() > 1:
        time.sleep(0.5)

    t = input("Create another batch (y/n)?\n").lower().strip() #
    if t != "y":
        print("Exiting.")
        break
```

---

Notes:

1. Avoid creating functions with the same name as builtin functions, like `sum()`, use
   `_sum()` or similar name;
2. Python is **caSe SenSiTive**, meaning that `Def` **isn't the same** as `def`, the same goes `For` / `for`;
3. Quote your strings with single `'` or double quotes
   `"`, **not** `’`;
4. [Live Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/019c9a01b0) - Python 3.6;
5. [Asciinema video](https://asciinema.org/a/238989).

Comment: That's not really how you [wait for threads to finish](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) in Python. Oh, and the other answer does take user input into account (`for n in range(T)`), it just didn't duplicate the OP's code ;) I like your notes, though, especially the first one.

Comment: The other question got updated in the meanwhile. *"That's note really how you ..."*, can be subjective. In this case, when the script starts, there's only one active thread , once we start multi-threading, the  `threading.active_count()` increases above 1 and when no "extra threads" are active, it returns to 1. Thank you for the remarks on the notes.

Comment: Sleep is terrible, never use it, except in tests/mocks, to simulate delays. Use thread's join method.